# Bind model change event to specific properties only

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, model, bind

Let's say I want to have two Event listeners, one for `myAttribute` property and another for the rest of the properties.

to solve this problem, i came up with this solution :

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults:function(){
        return {
                    myAttribute:'',
                    secondAttribute:'',
                    thirdAttribute:'',
                    only:'myAttribute'
        };
    },
    initialize:function(){

        this.listenTo(this,'change',this.listenUnlessOnly);
        this.listenTo(this,'change:'+this.get('only'),this.listenOnly);

    },
    listenUnlessOnly:function(){

        // make sure that attributeName doesn't belong to the list 
        // of updated attributes

        if(_.keys(this.changedAttributes()).indexOf(this.get('only')) === -1)             {
            alert('Another attribute changed');
        }else{
            // the other attribute changed so do nothing                 
        }                     
    },
    listenOnly:function(){            
        alert('Yoli myAttribute changed :) !!!');                
    }
});

var m = new Model();
m.set('username','hi'); // Another attribute changed
m.set('myAttribute','something'); // 'Yoli myAttribute changed :) !!!'
```

[Here is the jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ismnoiet/uf0thd0u/3/).

Where i registered two eventListeners one for the custom property(myAttribute) and another for the rest of the properties, and in the second eventlistener i'm checking if the updated property is not `myAttribute` to avoid firing 2 event.

Is there a default solution to cover this scenario ?
something like this :

```
this.listenTo(this,'change!myAttribute',this.listenUnlessOnly);
this.listenTo(this,'change:'+this.get('only'),this.listenOnly);
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: So what should happen when a bunch of attributes are changed at a time including `myAttribute`?

Comment: @TJ a good question, well in this case the other attributes will be handled by the other event listener and ``myAttribute`` will be handled by its event listener only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've to create only one listener for all cases

```
this.listenTo(this,'change',function(){
  var obj = this.changedAttributes();
  if(obj['myAttribute']){
    this.listenOnly();
    delete obj.myAttribute;
  }else if(_.keys(obj).length >=1){
    this.listenUnlessOnly();
  }
}.bind(this))
```